# Convert integer to unsigned 4 byte integer

Tags: php, sockets

How do I convert a PHP integer to a 4 byte unsigned integer in little endian byte order and prepend it to a string?

Below is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to be correct.

```
<?php
$message='some message';
$lng=strlen($message);
$lng_4_byte = pack("V", $lng);
$prependedMessage=$lng_4_byte.$message;
echo($prependedMessage);
```

Outputs some odd character which won't even display on this Stackoverflow post and `$prependedMessage` is shown as `\xC\x0\x0\x0some message` in IDE.

Comment: That sounds about right, yes. Did you expect anything else?

Comment: @deceze  Guess I expected something like `000A` if the length was 10.  Also, the client I am sending the message stream to doesn't seem to like it, so I thought I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Big-endian (`N`) would give you `\x0\x0\x0\xC`

Comment: @MarkBaker  That makes sense.  Am I correct how I just prepend this value to a string?  The receiving socket client is expecting the size of the message as the first 4 bytes.